Equivariant maps between $G$-Sets, with different groups; and a possible perspective on principal bundles
I was studying principal (smooth, Lie) bundles and I was trying to get my head around the definition of a morphism of principal bundles, and a few ideas came to my mind.
I tried looking online whether these things already existed out there, but I couldn't find anything, so I resorted to asking about it here, just out of curiosity.
I shall start with a few observation from the theory of group actions.
I am familiar with the notion of an equivariant map: essentially, they're the morphisms of group actions or $G$-Sets.
Let $G$ be a group and $X$, $X^\prime$ be sets with a (let's just say right, since we will be working with principal bundles) action of $G$; I will denote, such actions as maps, defined for every $g \in G$, $R_g \colon X \to X$ and $R^\prime _g \colon X^\prime \to X^\prime $. (You might object this is not really an action but rather a permutation representation).
We say a map $f \colon X \to X^\prime $ is an equivariant map if and only if for every $g \in G$ the following diagram commutes:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> X^\prime\\
@V R_g VV @VV R^\prime _g V\\
X @>>{f}> X^\prime
\end{CD}
First question: categorically speaking, this, rather than a diagram, looks like a "packet of diagrams", all indexed by the elements of $G$. I imagine stacking all of the "squares" one on top of the other, to get one gigantic diagram.
I know that category theory has a name for pretty much anything: does this thing have a name too?
Secondly; I initially assumed, years ago, that it would have made no sense to compare group actions for different groups. The same way that there is no notion of a linear map between vector spaces on different fields, I thought it would have made no sense to consider a morphism between a $G$-set and a $G^\prime$-set, where $G$ and $G^\prime$ are different groups. Instead, by studying principal bundles, I realized this notion could have had some use.
First I'll give you my "definition" and then I'll proceed to the application to principal bundles.
Let $X$, $X^\prime$ be sets with a right action of $G$ and $G^\prime$, respectively. We will use the same notation with $R_g$ and $R^\prime _g$, as before.
By a generalized equivariant map between $X$ as a $G$-set and $X^\prime$ as a $G^\prime$-set, we mean an ordered pair $(f, \theta)$, where $f \colon X \to X^\prime $ is a map and $\theta \colon G \to G^\prime $ is a group homomorphism, such that the following digram, for every every $g \in G$ commutes:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> X^\prime\\
@V R_g VV @VV R^\prime _{\theta(g)} V\\
X @>>{f}> X^\prime
\end{CD}
Once again: does this thing have a name already? Is there something I am missing here?
Obviously, the same idea of “stacking“ the diagrams from before applies here too, I would say.
Notice also that by choosing $G = G^\prime$ and $\theta = \mathrm{Id}$ we obtain the previous definition of an equivariant map.
Finally, let $(P, M, \pi, G)$ and $(P^\prime, M^\prime, \pi^\prime, G^\prime)$ be two principal (ideally, smooth) bundles. Recall that every principal $G$-bundle has a right action of its structure group. We will denote the actions of $G$ and $G^\prime$ on $P$ and $P^\prime$ as $R_g$ and $R^\prime _g$, respectively.
I'll follow my professor's textbook here: Natuaral and Gauge Natural Formalism for Classical Field Theories - Lorenzo Fatibene, Mauro Francaviglia, (Kluwer-Springer).
A principal bundle map (for different groups) is an ordered pair $(\mathbb{\Phi}, \theta)$ such that $\mathbb{\Phi} = (\Phi, \varphi)$ is a bundle map between $P \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} M$ and $P^\prime \overset{\pi^\prime}{\rightarrow} M^\prime$ and $\theta \colon G \to G^\prime$ is a (Lie) group homomorphism such that for every $g \in G$ the following diagram commutes:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
P @>{\mathbb{\Phi}}>> P^\prime\\
@V R_g VV @VV R^\prime _{\theta(g)} V\\
P @>>{\mathbb{\Phi}}> P^\prime
\end{CD}
In essence, a principal bundle map is, according to my made-up name, a generalized equivariant map, between $P$ and $P^\prime$, with respect to the right actions induced by $G$ and $G^\prime$.
I have seen that professor Schuller in his very famous playlist of lectures on YouTube, about the Geometric Anatomy of Physics goes one step further, using essentially the same definition, but by drawing an even more complicated diagram, one that also features the smooth map between the bases of the two bundles, and the projections, so that it is also clear that the map is also a bundle map.
So my final questions are:
are generalized equivariant maps actually a thing, or did I just make them up? It seems to me, they make everything simpler and the definitions clear and concise.
Also, we know that equivariant maps of group actions of a same group are the arrows of the category $G-\mathrm{Set}$. In other words, we need to fix the group if we want to get a sensible category.
But if what I am saying is true, could we conceive of a category of group actions, where we do not fix the group? Would that have the name of some categorical construction?
Last but not least, does this idea of stacking diagrams, or having a family of diagrams, indexed by some object (in this case, a group) have a name in category theory?
Thank you in advance.

First question: you are describing a natural transformation. $G$-sets are functors from $G$ (seen as a groupoid with a single object) to the category of sets, and equivariant maps are natural transformations between those.

Your generalised equivariant maps are also natural transformations, this time between $X$ and $X' \circ \theta$ (viewing group homomorphisms as functors).

(1) In your last diagram, the vertical arrow on the right should be labeled $R'{\theta(g)}$, not $R'\theta(g)$. (2) A homomorphism $\theta:G\to G'$ lets you convert any $G'$-set (i.e., set with $G'$-action) into a $G$-set, with the same underlying set $X'$ and with each $g\in G$ acting the same way as $\theta(g)\in G'$. This is the $X'\circ\theta$ in @NaïmFavier's second comment. Your generalized equivariant map then amounts to an equivariant map from $X$ to $X'\circ \theta$.  (This comment is essentially the same as Naim's, but without category terminology.)
